# SQL Server: pointing to the ID from other table

Tags: sql, pointers, sql-update

I have two tables: (`ID = int, Match = varchar, Status = char`)

**TableA**

```
ID1 Match1 Status1
23  1200   PASS
24  1300   FAIL
25  1400   PASS
26  1500   PASS
27  1600   FAIL
```

**TableB**

```
ID2 Match2 Status2
456 1200
784 1300
457 1300
124 1400
741 1600
```

Now, I want to populate `tableB (status2)` with 'FAIL' where there is fail in `tableA` (`match`).
so, I should get:

```
TableB
ID2 Match2 Status2
456 1200   NULL
784 1300   FAIL
457 1300   FAIL
124 1400   NULL
741 1600   FAIL
```

now this is pretty simple. I want to put in status2, ID1 which caused the fail so the expected result would be:

```
TableB
ID2 Match2 Status2
456 1200   NULL
784 1300   FAIL of ID 24
457 1300   FAIL of ID 24
124 1400   NULL
741 1600   FAIL of ID 27
```

I am currently using simple update statement as follows:

```
update B
set status2 = 'Fail'
from tableB B
Inner join tableA A
on a.match1 = b.match2
where a.status1 = 'FAIL'
```

Please correct to point to the ID1.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update B
set status2 = 'Fail of ID ' + CAST(A.ID1 AS VARCHAR(4))
from tableB B
Inner join tableA A
on a.match1 = b.match2
where a.status1 = 'FAIL'
```